# UIBarButtons and title are overlapping on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have a big Problem with my `UINavigationBar`. The back button is replaced with "back", the title is quite long and trimmed with trailing dots and i got a `UINavigationBarItem` on the right side.

[image]

The worst thing about this is when i move to the detail page and back to the broken `viewController` it's fixed automatically.

[image]

Is there a way to fix this? Any ideas?

**[UPDATE]**

If i add the button in the `viewDidLoad` method the Problem is gone. But if i want to add the Button after the viewDidLoad call it's broken… i can't fix this right now :/

Comment: The `back` button will be the title of the previous view controller, if you blank out that title you will get the behavior you see in the second picture of a chevron with no text, but it's unclear what you want from your question.

Comment: The iOS System default is a previous view controller title, if the title doesn't fit it will be replaced automatically by 'back' if 'back' will not fit it will be replaced with a empty string. I want the normal approach from Apple and not this kind of buggy overlay implementation on the top screenshot.

Comment: Ah, my experience has always been if I want the text blanked out, I always blank out the title of the previous view controller before I push the new one on, probably not the most elegant, but seems to work.

Comment: But i don't want this behavior it should depend on calculation from apple…

Comment: No it's for you to handle. I'd suggest an icon to replace the text on the right hand bar button to give you more space maybe?

Comment: It's only a Problem when i am adding the UIBarButtonItem, when i call my API and adding the button after the call. But i only know if there is a button after the API call :/